# How to pass a function to Enum.each?

Tags: elixir

I need to pass the items of list to a function, using Enum.each

```
ex:
users= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

#how to link the handler_user function in Enum.each?
users 
|> Enum.each handler_user

def handler_user user_id
end
```

So, how would I do the link?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use [&/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#&/1) to capture the function:

```
users = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Enum.each(users, &handler_user/1)

def handler_user(user_id) do
...
end
```

Comment: but, what if I want to send another parameter to handle_user, like owner_id? I will be calling &handler_user/2 but how to pass the other parameter?

Comment: Then you have to call the function:

`Enum.each(users, fn user -> handler_user(user, owner_id) end)`
` or  `Enum.each(users, &handler_user(&1, owner_id))`